# Getting Class reference of Subclass from Superclass

Tags: java

How can I get a reference to a Subclass's Class from a Superclass method?

E.g.,

```
public class MySuper {
  public void myMethod(){
    // here i need a reference to MySub1.class or MySub2.class
    // depending on the class of the instance that invoked this method
  }
}

public class MySub1 extends MySuper {
  public String myString;
}
public class MySub2 extends MySuper {
  public int myInt;
}
```

Comment: Has the object are already initialized or we need to initialize the object as and when we receive the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
Class<?> clazz = getClass();
```

Or more explicitly:

```
Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
```

Note that it won't be the class containing the code *that invoked the method* - it'll be the class of the object *that the method was invoked on*. If you want the class of the caller, that's a whole different matter.

Comment: thanks.  let's say I need to iterate through the fields of the Subclass (and populate them from JSON or XML or something)...  Will I be able to use reflection on clazz to myString for MySub1 instances and myInt for MySub2 instances?

Comment: @BigMoMo: Yes. Although personally I'd probably write a virtual method in `MySuper` to perform the serialization, and make subclasses override it to add their extra fields. I like doing serialization manually, unless you're using *entirely* autogenerated classes (such as with Protocol Buffers). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed.  The super has a generic serializer that just grabs primitives, which is overriden by subclasses that have non-primitive serialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `getClass()` you get the class of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
MySub1 sub1 = new MySub1();
sub1.getClass(); // returns the MySub1.
sub1.getClass().getSuperclass(); // returns MySuper
```

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: i guess he wants the reverse of this...subclass from a superclass